# Array.sort() giving wrong result

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am new to javascript and I was solving a puzzle on checkio, there I encountered an Array(unsorted) that needs to be sorted before proceeding further but its not working as expected.
below is the array and the array after sorting it using Array.sort().
`let arr = [ 3, 6, 20, 99, 10, 15 ];`

when I do the `arr.sort()`, I am getting the result as shown below
`[ 10, 15, 20, 3, 6, 99 ]` whereas it should be `[3,6,10,15,20,99]`
I tried the same in my node command line console and as well as google chrome's console but getting the same output.
can anyone help me with it?
Thank You.

Comment: Looks like it's sorting it alphabetically rather than numerically. Are you sure the array elements are numbers and not strings (that happen to contain digits)? Show us complete code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The title contradicts with the text.

Comment: @Jesper yes, they are numbers